# php date possible bug

Tags: php, date

I found a possible bug in PHP date function, if you run this code:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first monday 2020-06'));
```

the output is 2020-06-08 instead of 2020-06-01, is this a bug or i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php - "first Monday" and "first Monday **of**" work differently

Comment: The first seven days of the month are not necessarily the first calender week of the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put an "of" between first monday and the date
`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first monday of 2020-06 '));`
You can read about it at [relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: I’m happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can write first monday of june 2020 in strtotime() like below :

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first monday of june 2020"));
```